# In Wordpress Visual Composer, is it possible to set default values for the fields under Select Custom Fields?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

Specifically I'd like to give every new post a particular sidebar by default. Seems like setting default values should be possible, but I can't see where in the interface and a Google turned up nothing, so any advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can definitely set default values for parameters but your question is a little unclear: what do you mean by "...under Select Custom Fields"? It's not clear what this is.

Comment: Ah - on the site I was working on there was a 'Select Custom Fields' grouping of fields but I guess these aren't standard to Visual Composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the "value" property of the parameter array(s) for vc_map() or vc_add_parameter(). Documentation is [here](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524332#vc_map()-ParametersofparamsArray)... see the description of the *value* property.

An example would be:

```
function vc_myshortcode(){
    vc_map({
    'name' => 'My Shortcode',
    'base' => "myshortcode",
    'params' => array(
        array(
            'type'=>'textfield',
            'holder'=>'div',
            'param_name'=>'color',
            'value'=>'#333333'
        )
    )
})}
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'vc_myshortcode' );
```

So the default value for the *color* parameter would then be set to *#333333*

Comment: Thanks geoidesic, much appreciated.